# How do these search algorithm diagrams work? How am I supposed to interpret them? And what algorithms do those last three represent?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I was shown these diagrams in the context of search algorithms. The green tile shows the initial state, and the orange tile shows the goal state. I am told that each option shows a path each search method would take to reach the goal state.

This one is apparently breadth-first search:

[image]

This one is apparently bidirectional breadth-first search:

[image]

This one seems to be Dijkstra's algorithm and A$^*$:

[image]

I'm not sure what these ones are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I don't really understand how these diagrams work. How do these diagrams work? How am I supposed to interpret them? And what algorithms do those last three represent?

Comment: Can you credit the original source where you saw these diagrams?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: @D.W. It's an internal university document, so I cannot. But I can assure you that I am authorised to use this.